# Advanced Fraction with several Level

Tags: tikz-pgf, fractions

I would like to ask, how could I use `LaTex` to create following tools refer to the uploaded graph. Do  you have some idea to mock such tool in following graph?

Some descriptions:

1. The Tool is for calculation following the order. The tool starts from bottom. Like **the first example**, we aim to calculate `3 + 4 * 8 - 12`.Step by step we separate the terms util we have `4 * 8` then we get `32`. After that we replace the `4 * 8` using `32` to get the `3 + 32 => 35` . Last step we `35 - 12` using the `35` from the round earlier and come to `23` as our final result.
2. I try some way with `fraction` because the base part is like fraction in math. But left of the **fraction line** we always have some alphabets.
3. Is `tikz` for this situation necessary? Because I always have  to leave enough space above the **fraction line**, for the level above, which can be large. Refer to the second example.

[image: First example]

[image: Second example]

Comment: This is doable with `\frac` only...

Comment: @Werner Yes, that's what the (earlier) answer below shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! I am afraid you do not need Ti*k*Z for that. (Added `\mathrel`, big thanks to Peter Grill!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\DeclareMathOperator{\OP}{OP}
\newcommand{\cra}{\mathrel{\textcolor{cyan}{\Rightarrow}}}
\begin{document}
\[
 \OP\frac{\displaystyle\OP\frac{\displaystyle 
 \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{}{3\cra3}\quad\OP
 \frac{4\cra4\quad8\cra8\quad4\mathbin{\textcolor{red}{*}}8\cra32}{4*8\cra35}\quad
 \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{}{3\mathbin{\textcolor{red}{+}}32\cra35}
 }{3+4*8\cra35}\quad
 \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{}{12\cra12~35\mathbin{\textcolor{red}{-}}12\cra23}}{3+4*8-12\cra23}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Shout `\cra` perhaps be a `\mathrel{}`?